# Selecting one Landsat image per year according to cloud cover using Google Earth Engine JavaScript API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, imagecollection

I'd like to create a Landsat 5,7 and 8 Image Collection for a given location, selecting for each year (and within the January to march month range) the scene with the least cloud cover.

So far I have homogenized the Landsat bands in a single collection and applied the Bounds and date ranges, but I cannot find a tool that would pick up a single image per year according to the lowest cloud coverage.

I have looked at the limit and sort tools, but I am still missing something. Below is my preliminary script.

```
//This code generates a landsat-family temporal series for a given location and
//provides a list of annual images with the least cloud cover. 

//homogenize Landsat family bands
var L8_bands = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7'];
var L7_bands = ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B7'];
var L5_bands = ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B7'];
var STD_NAMES = ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'nir', 'swir1', 'swir2'];

var l8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA').select(L8_bands, STD_NAMES);// Landsat 8
var l7 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_TOA').select(L7_bands, STD_NAMES); //Landsat 7
var l5 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_TOA').select(L5_bands, STD_NAMES); //Landsat 5

var lmerge = l8.merge(l7).merge(l5);
var lmerge_filter = lmerge.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1985,2023,'year')).filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1,3,'month'))
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'Less_Than', 20);
print(lmerge_filter, 'collection');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function that selects the image with the lowest `CLOUD_COVER` for a given `year`, then map that function to a list of years that you want.

```js
function leastCloudyImageByYear(year){
  // Select the least cloudy image by year
  return lmerge_filter.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(year,year,'year'))
  .sort("CLOUD_COVER").first()
}
var result = ee.ImageCollection(ee.List.sequence(1985,2023).map(leastCloudyImageByYear))
print(result) // 34 images
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/fa6978679ed4b9cd420deaac103125c5